# cant get jquery to work with php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache2, webserver, document-root

I have a linux webserver that has `/var/www` configured in the Apache2.conf file as the DocumentRoot.  Next I have my jquery core file located at `/var/www/js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js` (a central location for all my websites to access.

The `.php` index file is located at `/var/www/AOI/aoiparse.php`, where the aoifunctions.js file is also located.  My `<head>` tag looks as follows:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' scr='/js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' scr='aoifunctions.js'></script>
```

my aoifunctions.js file has the following in it in order to verify that the script link works:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     alert("hello");
  });
```

My problem is that I cannot get the alert() to work. I'm not getting an error message so I do not know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js'></script>`

(The attribute is **src**, not scr, plus your path was incorrect)

Comment: The path might have been correct; in fact, it probably was if `/var/www` was the host's DocumentRoot.

Comment: wow, stupid me, misspelling a 3 letter word.  Thank you for pointing that out. Surprisingly I have been banging my head against the wall for about an hour now.

Answer (score 1):

put the jquery file in /var/www/AOI/js/ and then
remove the first /

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js'></script>
```

so it lies in a subdirectory to your main page

or use this if you want to leave it where it is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js'></script>
```

Comment: The path was probably correct; it looks like `/var/www` is his host's DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "src" in your `<script>` tags. It's short for SouRCe.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jQuery_v1.4.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='aoifunctions.js'></script>
```

If you used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) you'd have been able to easily tell that the scripts weren't loaded.